# Finding if Long-Lat coordinate falls under a specific region in ArcGIS Online map

Tags: python, geojson, layers, arcgis-online, tiles

I am very new to this.

I am working with this map: [Poverty & Disadvantaged Census Tracts](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5ae23bc50925436881a44d35efb6acdf)

I have a collection of longitude and latitude coordinates and I am trying to check if they intersect one of the regions highlighted in the map above as AoPP or HDC, and collect the features associated with that region if it does use Python.

I have tried to convert the map into a Multipolygon/GeoJSON format through an API request, but the coordinate system is different, and I can't find a recourse that says it's even possible.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. AS a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to contain exactly what  you attempted, so we can look for the problem.